# remove last 10 rows of a csv file in bash

Tags: node.js, bash, csv

i have a CSV file and want to remove the last 10 records or rows of it so if we have 100 records (100 rows) so i can delete last 10 and have just 90 rows
and i want to do it in bash(or node js if you know how to do it)

Comment: What did you try? You can easily get it done with `head`.

Comment: how can i do this with head? i did this head -n 5 sample.csv but it removes 5 line from the csv not 5 rows

Comment: Wait, what's the difference between a row and a line?

Comment: Are you confusing rows and columns?

Comment: i dont want to remove 10 line i want to remove 10 row

Comment: @Vfx Master, after seeing your profile got to know that you never select an answer as correct one out of all.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `head` command with a **negative** value of n to remove the *n last lines* (you're talking about *rows*, I assumed it was *lines*):

```
head -n -10 file.csv
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked but with head -n -10 file.csv it removes 2 row,with -n -100 it removes 8 rows and with -n -300 removes 23 rows and i have no idea how this works but thx anyway as it solves my problem

Comment: this code removes 10 line from the last how can i remove 10 rows from the last?

Comment: @VfxMaster, I still don't understand what you mean by row, and what's the difference with a line. Also your results (2 rows for 10 lines, and so on) are pretty surprising. Maybe you could past it on a pastebin site and add a link here (be careful with sensitive datas).

Comment: @VfxMaster, also check out your ends of line. Are they a mix of Windows and Unix? Execute dos2unix your_file.csv to fix it just in case.